# SQL Server trigger thinks there's a duplicate in the table when there isn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, exists

I'm a new SQL developer. After recommendations I have altered my trigger (for this task I need to use a trigger so can't avoid it), but I have re-altered my trigger. I want it to prevent a duplication in the `Rentals` table of the `BikeID` foreign key contained within it.

This is my code at the moment:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BikeNotAvailable 
ON dbo.SA_Rental
AFTER INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM SA_Rental
               INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.BikeID = dbo.SA_Rental.BikeID)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RAISERROR ('This bike is already being hired', 16, 1);
    END
go
```

But when I enter the `BikeID` in the `Rentals` table, even though the `BikeID` is not present inside a row yet, it still raises the error - why? (I have also tested this on an empty table and it still raises the error)

Just some context on my data, the `BikeID` is a primary key from the 'Bike' table that is shared as a foreign key to the `Rentals` table, not sure if this has anything to do with the error.

Can someone please help me fix this trigger so it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Your trigger is an **`AFTER INSERT`**, so of course the value will exist in the table after you have inserted it. You'd be far better off using a Unique Index to do this, rather than a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it's an AFTER trigger, the trigger is run *after* the new record is added to the table (at least visible for your trigger).

Supposing that your table has an automatically generated ID column, you should exclude the inserted row from your check like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BikeNotAvailable ON dbo.SA_Rental
AFTER INSERT
AS
  if exists ( select * from SA_Rental
  inner join inserted i on i.BikeID=dbo.SA_Rental.BikeID
  where SA_Rental.RentalID <> i.RentalID)
  begin
    rollback
    RAISERROR ('This bike is already being hired', 16, 1);
  end
go
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply @wolfgang Kais. I've tried this out, but it doesn't work. BikeID is actually a varchar(50), so how would I change the above code for it to work? Thanks.

Comment: @NoName788 I didn't suggest to do anything with the BikeID. What is the primary key of the rentals table?

Comment: The primary key for the rentals table is 'RentalID' which is an int

Comment: @NoName788, Yes, that's what I assumed and that's what I suggested to compare in the additional WHERE clause. So what isn't working? (Just edited my reply and replaced ID with RentalID)

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I misunderstood, thank you very much works like a charm! :D

Comment: No problem. Please also have a look at the answer from @Lamu. A unique index could prevent duplicate BikeIDs as well, and it would be checked **before** the duplicate BikeID is inserted.

Answer (score 2):

A far simpler way to achieve what you are after is to create a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BikeRented ON SA_Rental (BikeID);
```

This, of course, *assumes* that you delete the row from your table when the bike is no longer rented (as this is the implied logic in your post). If this is not the case, then we need more detail; what specifies on your table that the rental has completed?

If we ***assume*** you have a return date, and the return date is `NULL` when the bike is yet to be returned, then you would use a filtered index like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BikeRented ON SA_Rental (BikeID)
WHERE ReturnedDate IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Lamu, thanks for your reply. Wolfgang Kais's suggestion did what I needed, it was mainly to make the bike unavailable and I needed to use the trigger as per requirements. But I appreciate you taking your time out to reply.